# How to send a dynamic message email

Tags: vb.net, email, visual-studio-2005

I'm writing a program that will scan a barcode from a serial scanner and store the information in a MySQL database.

In the program I would like to check for when the scanner is not working. If it's not working then send me an email. I set a variable called `MessageBody` which sets the body of the email that is going to be sent. The subroutine is called `EmailError()`. So I can call it in other subroutines. I would like to take a variable or something and put it in the Message body so I can have a dynamic message body and not a static boring one.

Any Ideas?

I'm sure I wasn't clear enough so please ask questions.

Comment: Can't you just concatenate a string together?

Comment: Or if you wanted you could include placeholders that `String.Format()` could parse out later, like `There was an error with program {0} at {1}`.

Comment: In order to get information from one sub routine to another wouldn't I need to pass data into `EmailError()`?

Comment: yes, that's exactly what you'd do. I don't think I understand what your actual question is.

Comment: A slight aside to the actual question but how will you know that a serial device is working or not? `(No data received) = (Not read anything) <> (Broken or Unplugged or Stolen)`

Comment: Yeah basically. I used Symbols API called SSI that comes with the Symbol scanners.

Answer (score 0):

I found a link that might be of use to you.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/mailtemplates.aspx

You could create a simpler version, maybe have a good file and a bad file, in the case of putting together the body of the email in the EmailError method you could simply read the file in, replace certain keywords like  with variable values. In the past I've used something that the String.Format can understand, so the file would have something like

```
Dear {0},

Thank you for submitting your message. You are customer number {1}.

If you have any questions please contact our helpdesk at: 555-555-5555 or email them at helpdesk@somedomain.com
```

Then opening the file for read, storing it in a variable and modifying the values using `string value = String.Format(myFileContents, firstName, customerNumber);` would be the email body.

Hopefully this helps a bit. There are many other techniques too, xslt for transforming, jxls (velocity and excel templates in java) or the NVelocity version for .net http://nvelocity.sourceforge.net/